# Laravel: How to make a relationship between two table that has a reference table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have 3 tables.

**People, Assignments and Projects**

> each person in People table can be assigned to one or more Projects.
>   Each project in Projects table can have one ore more person assigned to it.

Here are the columns of each table:

People

- id
- name

Assignments:

- person_id
- project_id

Projects

- id
- title

My question is: in my Project model, how do I define the relationship?

What I want is to be able to get the names of all person assigned to a specific project.

I NEED:

```
$project->assignedPeople
```

So I can:

```
foreach($projects as $project)
$project->title
  foreach(projects->assignedPeople as $person)
  $person->name
```

I NEED YOUR HELP PLEASE
THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1):

Actually You need Many-to-Many relationship.

You can define the Models like this

**Project Model**

```
class Project extends Model {

    public function peoples()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\People');
    }
}
```

And

**People Model**

```
class People extends Model {

    public function projects()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Project');
    }
}
```

Now you can access the names of all person assigned to a specific project like this.

```
$project->peoples
```

And you can run your foreach loop like this

```
foreach($projects as $project) {
    echo $project->title;
    foreach(project->peoples as $person) {
        echo $person->name;
    }
}
```

Hope it may solve your problem.

Thanks

Comment: And where does the reference table comes into this solution? Both tables doesn't know without reference table, where to lookup.

Comment: @Sascha the reference table will auto generate/maintain based on the relation. But if you want to do some customisation that you can do as well. Like the table name, column name change and so on. ``` return $this->belongsToMany('App\Project', 'projects_peoples', 'project_id', 'people_id');
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
// Inside Model Project
class Project extends Model {
    
    public function people()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\People');
    }
    
}
    
// Inside Model People
class People extends Model {
    
    public function project()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Project');
    }    

}

// In case of custom joining table:
class People extends Model {
    
    public function project()
    {
         return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Project', 'Assignments', 'person_id', 'project_id');
    }
    
}
```